# What is the wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt used for?

Tags: security

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I stumbled upon that certificate. I would like to know what it is for. Is Wp using it in any way? Can I delete it (or move it outside the document root)?
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deleting files from the WordPress core in general.

Answer (score 7):

### ca-bundle.crt File

It is an SSL Certificate file which WordPress uses as default for secure connections (https) when WordPress make request using [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)

This file is used in [`/wp-includes/class-http.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-http.php#L133) file. It is a WordPress default file (never remove anything from WP core!) so removing it will cause problem for the class to work properly.

Comment: And I'd like to add with Sisir that, it's not a security issue (perhaps it's making your thing a bit secured :) ), and deleting core files is a bad thing to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

This file is supposed to solve the issue of communicating with wordpress.org for updates over HTTPS (and also helps with other https based communication). Not all hosts install the root certificates that are required by the cURL library  in order to be able to authenticate that a host is actually who its says it is, which leads to errors of the type of "can not communicate with wordpress.org". Instead of relying on the host to be properly configured wordpress supplies the certificates with core.

That file do not have any real security info and in theory you can delete it if your server is properly configured, but at the next wordpress update it will be reinstalled so it is kinda pointless.